# simple mail function not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I have this sending mail code in Codeigniter controller.

```
$config['useragent'] = 'CodeIgniter';
$config['protocol'] = 'sendmail';
$config['mailpath'] = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
$config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;                    
$this->load->library('email');
$this->email->initialize($config);
$this->email->from('mymail@yahoo.com', 'myname');
$this->email->to('testingmail@gmail.com'); 
$this->email->subject('Email Test');
$this->email->message('Testing .'); 
$this->email->send();
echo $this->email->print_debugger();
```

But it shows `unable to send email using PHP mail()`. Please help me to solve the issue.

Comment: linux OS we are using

Comment: may be you have not configured mail settings in php.ini

Comment: Try to send a mail with the php native `mail()` function and see if it works or not.

Comment: i have write $to = "sample@gmail.com";
$subject = "Test mail";
$message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
$from = "someonelse@example.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

Comment: but i did nt get mail

Comment: @ Harish Singh how to  configured mail settings in php.ini?

Answer (score 1):

Check your PHP configuration (php.ini) for proper `mail` values:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
;SMTP = localhost
;smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
;sendmail_from = me@example.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail
```

Comment/uncomment lines depending on your OS.
You also may need to install `sendmail` utility.

Comment: i am using linuzxOS. how to install sendmail utility in codeignter

Comment: @Ammu What distro do you use?

Comment: phpdesigner sometimes dw

Comment: @Ammu no, I'm asking you about your Linux distro.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $this->load->library('email');
    $this->email->from('');
    $this->email->to('');
    $this->email->subject('subject');
    $this->email->set_mailtype('html');
    $datas['title'] = "title";
    $datas['footer'] = '&copy; '.date("Y").' www.aaa.com  All rights reserved';
    $con1 = '
            <p style="Calibri, Verdana, Ariel, sans-serif; font-size:11px;  color:#666666"> Hello , </p>
            <p class="commen_text" style="font:Calibri, Verdana, Ariel, sans-serif; font-size:11px;font-weight:normal;  color:#666666;text-align:justify;">content here.</p>
            ';
    $con2 ='        
            <p class="commen_text" style="font:Calibri, Verdana, Ariel, sans-serif; font-weight:normal;font-size:11px;color:#666666;text-align:justify;">Please download the attachement.&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
            <p style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(235, 235, 235); font-size: 1px; margin-top: 0px;">&nbsp;</p>
            ';
    $this->email->attach('/path/of/the/file');
    $datas['content']=$con1.$con2;

    $msg = $this->load->view('include/email_template', $datas, TRUE);  // create base html file and echo title, content and footer there
    $this->email->message($msg);
    $this->email->send();
```

Comment: if you have any doubt please refer http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/email.html

Answer (score 0):

I dont why you still want to use mail function instead use  email class
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/email.html

You can use user gmail smtp setting to send emails . which is more Robust.

If this is only for testing I would suggest you to use Mailtrap SMTP  its free and used only for testing emails.

If you want a lib  you can use this : https://github.com/jaiwalker/mailtrap